# Select same rows from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

In df1, I would like to have only the same ID rows as in df2. How can I select rows that are in df2 based on ID and drop the other rows?

```
     df1             
     ID Var1    Var2    Col1    Col2
     1    34      22      34      24
     2     3      25      54      65
     3    87      68      14      78
     4    66      98      98     100
     5    55      13      77       2

     df2             
     ID Varx    VarY    ColZ    Col2
     1    134      2      4      4
     2     33      5      4      5
     4    660      8      8      100




     Expected outcome:
     df1             
     ID Var1    Var2    Col1    Col2
     1    34      22      34      24
     2     3      25      54      65
     4    66      98      98     100
```

Comment: You can use `dplyr::semi_join` or `inner_join` depending on whether your IDs are unique

Comment: I tried df_final <- semi_join(df1, df2) and it didnt seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: you didn't specify `by = "ID"`

Comment: Thanks Calum! Works great now.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df1[df1$ID %in% df2$ID, ]
```